# Computing Irreducible Components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

I'm doing an exercise from Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* and wanted to make sure my thinking was correct. The exercise asks to find the irreducible components of $V(y^2-x(x^2-1))$ and $V(x^3+x-x^2y-y)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$ where $V$ denotes the zero loci of the given ideals.

My solution:

For the first one, we claim that $y^2-x(x^2-1)$ is irreducible, because any non unit factor would have to have degree $1$ in $y$, so suppose $y^2-x(x^2-1) = (y+a(x))(y+b(x))$. Then we get that $a(x) = -b(x)$, implying that $y^2-x(x^2-1) = y^2-a^2(x)$. Since $x(x^2-1)$ is not a square this cannot happen so the polynomial, and hence the algebraic set is irreducible. This holds for both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

For the second one, the factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ is $(x-y)(x^2+1)$ which are both irreducible so $$V(x^3+x-x^2-y) = V(x-y)\cup V(x^2+1)$$ and over $\mathbb{C}$ we get an additional componenet $$V(x^3+x-x^2-y) = V(x-y)\cup V(x-i) \cup V(x+i)$$.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Unless there's a typo somewhere, your second factorization is wrong.

Comment: @KReiser there was a typo, thanks!